# How to Add Numbers in a Matrix to Yield Minimum Result?

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

This is more of an algorithmic/math problem but I'm hoping to implement a solution in C++.

Suppose I have a matrix like so where the dots represent integers:

```
   W  X  Y  Z
A  .  .  .  . 
B  .  .  .  .
C  .  .  .  .
D  .  .  .  .
```

How would I yield the minimum result if I had to pick one number from each column such that there is at most one number from each row?

For instance, I could choose `AW  BX  CY  DZ`  or  `AZ  BX  CY  DW`  but NOT `AW BW CZ DZ`

The brute force approach would seem to take n! calculations. Is there a quicker way? Eventually I would like to add numbers in matrices of size ~60.

Also, all numbers range from 0 to 256.

Comment: n factorial indeed. my mistake.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm
Your question looks similar to this problem.

Comment: Let's assume you start with AW, BX or BW, AX: In both cases, A, B rows and W, X columns would be out. Thinking along those lines recursively and caching the results should do the trick. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming

Comment: @Tarik, 4 cases instead of 2 take out rows A,B and columns W,X: AW-BX; BX-AW; AX-BW; BW-AX.  Anyway, I agree dynamic programming is a plausible approach

Comment: @user2548103 Why don't you post it as an answer? The question doesn't only look "similar", it is *exactly* the same problem. :) (if we suppose that the "result" that the OP is talking about is the sum of the picked integers)

Answer (score 1):

And if you'd rather not code it yourself, you could always use someone else' hard-work and kind publication. This one in Haskell, solves a 60x60 random matrix in less than two tenths of a second on my old laptop. What a great algorithm!

```
import Data.Algorithm.Munkres
import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Data.List (transpose)

solve n matrix = 
  hungarianMethodInt (listArray ((1,1),(n,n)) $ concat $ transpose matrix)
```